# conda broken after upgrade to 4.2.6

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, conda

Sorry, new to stackoverflow and ubuntu. I upgraded conda to 4.2.6 and now every time I use a conda command I get the following error.

> @user:~$ conda list
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/local/bin/conda", line 5, in 
>       from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-20.6.7- py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2900, in
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-20.6.7-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2886, in _call_aside
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-20.6.7-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2913, in _initialize_master_working_set
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-20.6.7-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 637, in _build_master
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-20.6.7-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 650, in _build_from_requirements
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-20.6.7-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 829, in resolve
>   pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'conda==4.0.5' distribution was not found and is required by the application

I tried changing 4.0.5 to 4.2.6 in the conda file in /usr/local/bin/ but that didn't fix it.

Any ideas? Many thanks!

Comment: How did you update conda?  In any case try fully uninstalling all copies of it on your system and reinstall through your distribution's package manager (if you are using that) and remove any relevant egg-info directories in `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages` (be very careful if you are doing this - only remove conda-4.0.5.egg-info or whatever else if the uninstallation was done incorrectly).

Comment: Many thanks @metatoaster, I used "sudo conda update conda". What's the safest way to uninstall conda given I can't use "conda uninstall" (it throws the same error as above)?

Comment: Also, how did you originally install conda? You might want to restart from that step but using the new version instead. If conda is its own package manager you should report this bug to the package owner as their updates breaking their own software is a pretty major bug.

Comment: Many thanks @metatoaster. In the end I installed anaconda on top of it and that seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem. How did you solve it?